# Mi función devuelve null cuando debería devolver un objeto

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, null, else

¡Hola!

Tengo un problema con una función llamada `buscarPorModelo` la cual recibe el `modelo` de un producto y entrega todos los datos de ese producto en forma de `objeto`, si el modelo no coincide con ninguno de la lista muestra un `null`, sin embargo esto sólo me funciona para el primero de mis objetos, si trato de buscar otro siempre muestra `null` pese a que el `modelo` existe dentro de mi `array` y no entiendo el por qué.

Este es mi código:

```js
let electronicos = [
    {producto: "Televisor HD", modelo: "ABB56", marca: "sony", precio: 14000 },
    {producto: "Monitor 4K", modelo: "KLA782", marca: "benq", precio: 7200 },
    {producto: "Pantalla LED", modelo: "PSW757", marca: "LG", precio: 9100 }
];

let carrito ={
    buscarPorModelo: function(modelo) {
        for ( let i = 0; i < electronicos.length; i ++ ) {
            if (electronicos[i].modelo === modelo){
                return electronicos[i]
            } 
            else 
            return null
        }
    }
};

//Con el primero de mis objetos no hay problema, en cosola me muestra el objeto al que pertenece ese modelo
console.log (carrito.buscarPorModelo("ABB56"));

//Pero si busco al tercer producto me muestra null
console.log (carrito.buscarPorModelo("PSW757"));
```

```
//Con el primero de mis objetos no hay problema, en cosola me muestra el objeto al que pertenece ese modelo
console.log (carrito.buscarPorModelo("ABB56"));

//Pero si busco al tercer producto me muestra null
console.log (carrito.buscarPorModelo("PSW757"));
```

Si no utilizo `else` funciona bien pero en el ejercicio me indican que debe retornar `null`.
Espero me puedan ayudar porque pensé que estaba hecho correctamente hasta que busqué el segundo de mis objetos :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea sería lo siguiente que te acabo de poner, si lo encuentra dentro del for, devuelve el objeto, pero si al acabar no lo ha encontrado, retornara null.

```js
let electronicos = [
    {producto: "Televisor HD", modelo: "ABB56", marca: "sony", precio: 14000 },
    {producto: "Monitor 4K", modelo: "KLA782", marca: "benq", precio: 7200 },
    {producto: "Pantalla LED", modelo: "PSW757", marca: "LG", precio: 9100 }
];

let carrito ={
    buscarPorModelo: function(modelo) {
        for (let i = 0; i < electronicos.length; i++) {
            if (electronicos[i].modelo === modelo) {
                return electronicos[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};

//FUNCIONA
console.log (carrito.buscarPorModelo("ABB56"));
//FUNCIONA
console.log (carrito.buscarPorModelo("PSW757"));

//DEVUELVE NULL PORQUE NO EXISTE
console.log (carrito.buscarPorModelo("Anime:)"));
```

Espero haberte ayudado, para cualquier método que su función sea la búsqueda de un objeto dentro de un Array o lista, la mejor forma sería la mostrada.

Comment: Ah, ya entendí! Tenía que colocar el null por fuera del ciclo for. Sabía que era algo sencillo pero no encontraba el problema :( ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra poder haberte ayudado.